# Need help to identify a brand of a japanese cruiser women bike

Tags: cruiser, women-specific, drum-brakes, japan

I've just purchased this bike from someone who could not tell me the brand. She told me it was Japanese (information provided by the previous owner). This bike has many atypical features, at least to me, therefore I try to identify its brand/model/year online without success. I hope we can help me identify the brand. Here are the features:

- SAKURA tires 37 X 590 (ISO) with Japanese/dunlop tube
- Shimano rear derailleur
- KALIN handlebar stem
- ARAI Internal rear (Drum) brake (90 Band Brake) and front Rim Brake
- Shimano MF-TZ20 6-speed freewheel + Shimano Revoshift SIS index
- SUSTEK Saddle and handles
- SANYO Dynamo front light
- Large enough back rack to carry a metal baby seat
- GORIN Ring rear wheel lock

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have many other pictures, and also the serial number starting STLCA24...
Any advice or help would be very welcome!
Thank you so much,
Julien

[image]

Comment: Is there a head-tube badge? If so please add a photo with [edit]

Comment: Hi Criggie, just add it! I hope that will help!

Comment: It has some of the characteristics of a rental bike. Rugged, no-nonsense transportation.

Comment: "the original bike components" usually means "the *original low-quality* *cloned* bike components".
Yes, the low-quality is original to the cloned bike component :)

Comment: Hi @julien-ottawa, I don't see a picture of the head tube (the last picture with a sticker is the seat tube I think).  In case you are not sure: the head tube is the tube of the frame in which the handlebar stem and fork meet.  I suspect it actually doesn't have a badge in this case.

Comment: @DavidD, especially the quick release for the seat post seems typical for a rental bike to me.

Comment: Not an answer - but why do you need to identify the brand of the bike?

Comment: @Superman.Lopez you are right, nothing on the headtube

Comment: @Criggie mostly out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the hub generator it looks a lot like this [Bobby Town bicycle](http://rezepty.org/bike_maid-246).
[image]
[image]
Searching for "bobby town bicycle" will pop up a couple other bikes.

Bikes like this are widely sold in Japan.
[From Asahi's website they have bike classification of city cycle](https://ec.cb-asahi.co.jp/category/cat1/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AB). Some of them with frames similar to the bike in question

I'm pretty sure that Bobby Town is the model. The head tube label is not visible in this picture. I found another similar bike that had "CBA Velociste" in the head tube and I believe that is the name of the company.

Thanks to Superman.Lopez for the clue on the type of bicycle.

Comment: The warning sticker looks identical - which implies its the same backend company doing the frame building, OR its a generic sticker that could be on many Japanese bikes.

Comment: Thank you so much David!!!! :D

Comment: Exactly the same here, you are definitly right about the brand: https://www.carousell.ph/p/bobby-town-japan-bike-27-1130673643/

Answer (score 3):

> Mamachari, a slang term literally meaning “mom’s bike,” are Japan’s ubiquitous city bicycles. Featuring baskets and, often, child seats

> Mamachari A functional and sturdy bicycle used mainly to run errands in the neighborhood. They feature an L- or U-shaped top tube, 24- to 26-inch (540–559 mm) wheels, and a basket, and can be equipped with child seats for up to two children.

https://www.nippon.com/en/features/jg00091/

This seems to be a generic non-branded mamachari bike.  I doubt you'd find a brand, model or year for it.  What is your concern about the "atypical" features?  Judging from your list and the pictures these all seem quite common and generic parts.

Comment: thank you for that!! atypical for me, living in canada :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a practical bike, but in my view the bolt holding in place the seat tube *and* the seat stays seems very dangerous (i.e. do not carry a child on that back seat).

Final note: Japan exported extreme high quality bicycles, and it still exports components of extreme quality, but the domestic bicycle market is flooded with extremely cheap bicycle [1] ... it seems yours is one of them. If you are in the US, it looks cool and unique, compared to the average Walmart bicycle, but in Japan a Walmart bicycles would look cool and unique.

[1] it is a common macro-economic practice: suppress the salaries of the worker of a certain country, so the currency value stays low since the *workers* cannot buy much from abroad or at least from richer countries, while at the same time pushing up the values (strong public investments in R&D, joining free trade agreement) of your products so they can be exported, since they cost less.